# Add product jar cost to product price

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have a site made on Magento 2.1, which sales proteins product for bodybuilders. I have to provide 2 option for product

1. sale product with Pouch with no additional cost
2. sale product with Jar which will have some cost.

My question is how can I provide such options also If jar option is selected it should automatically get added to product price.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use custom options for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Magento 2` custom option feature. Just open the product which you want to add this feature and go to custom option tab and add your option, like

[image]

You can add price according to your requirement.

Comment: You can try configurable product option also...

Comment: @Keyur Shah I think the custom option is better. So I accepted the answer